# How to redirect before rendering page in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am wondering if I can redirect a user before rendering a page in Next.js?

Right now I have this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function RedirectPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    router.push('/projects');

    return (
        <div><h1>hi</h1></div>
    )
}
```

With this error: `Error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) by having a 'redirect' property on the returned object.

```
export default function RedirectPage() {
    return (
        <div><h1>hi</h1></div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/projects',
      permanent: false,
    },
  }
}
```

I can't say if this will render the page on server or not, but the user will be redirected and not be shown the content of the redirect page.

Comment: What if we want to conditionally redirect based on `window.location.hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/projects');
},[])

return null
```

may be this work

Answer (score 0):

Use the Router class to redirect

```
import Router from "next/Router"

export default function RedirectPage() {

    Router.push({
       pathname: '/projects'
    })

    return (
        <>Redirecting ....</>
    )
}

This way you dont have to make an instance
```